# Image Processing I cannot handle

Tags: image

The image on the left is the input, and the image on the right is the output. How can I achieve the transformation from the left image to the right image? It seems that low-pass filtering and edge extraction are not enough to solve this problem.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see any images. Did I miss something?